# PHP preg_replace() multiple different matches

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i am doing a script in php, and i need to use preg_replace or something similar to add some tags in front of and behind matches. For example i have this pattern (regular expression which i am parsing from a file) and text:

```
$pattern = aa*
$string = "Example, exaaample"
```

Basicly, what i need is to add some tags in front of and behind all matches, so it will look like this:

```
"Ex<t>a</t>mple, ex<t>aaa</t>mple
```

Is there any way how to make this happen? I am pretty sure it's not that complicated but I am stuck on this for quite a while. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. You can do it like this:

```
 preg_replace("/(aa*)/", "<t>$1</t>")
```

`$1` will be replaced by the matched pattern.

Comment: thanks, but is it possible without changing pattern? I am parsing it from a file, therefore i don't know how it exactly looks

Comment: What do you mean by 'without changing pattern'?

Comment: i mean that my regular expression for finding matches was "aa*" and you used "(\w)(a+)(\w)"

Comment: yes, that's exactly what i mean. Thanks for your help. Btw, this should work for any regex i put as pattern right?